# Build Index to an existing table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

How can I re-index (build the index by the existing data) to a table in my Ruby on Rails app?

I have created the following migration file:

```
class AddIndexProductImagesOnProductId < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :product_images, :product_id
  end
end
```

After hitting the

```
rake db:migrate
```

the following index was indeed added to the schema.rb

```
  add_index "product_images", ["product_id"], name: "index_product_images_on_product_id", using: :btree
```

But the existing data is still un-indexed and only new added data is being indexed.

How can I index the existing data of that table? (I'm using Postgres)

Comment: how are you proving existing data is not being indexed?

Comment: The query is still very slow (same performance) and Postgresql Studio shows "Index Scans = 5". 
it started with 1, and now it's 5 only I have added rows to the table.

Comment: @GuyDubrovski that is not how indexes work. All the values are indexed (except NULLs), so what you have is a "why is postgresql not using my index" question.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAldridge, do you have any idea why would postgres not use the index? :/

Comment: let's provide your query here, may be that query is not using your index as expected. Btw you can use newrelic to monitor your database performance  https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/applications-menu/monitoring/viewing-slow-query-details

Comment: Here is the query that is being generated:
ProductImage Load (153.5ms)  
SELECT  "product_images".* FROM "product_images" WHERE "product_images"."product_id" = $1  ORDER BY position LIMIT 1  [["product_id", 359529]]

Comment: Show the generated SQL, give estimate of data volume, and the might lead to an answer

Comment: How many rows in product_images? Can you run a PostgreSQL explain plan?

Comment: I have around 1 Million records in that table.
How can I check the Explain Plan?

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "product_images".* FROM "product_images" WHERE "product_images"."product_id" = $1 ORDER BY position LIMIT 1` for example.